# Disable left quick launch keys on hp g62 laptop

Tags: windows, keyboard, hotkeys

I have an HP g62 laptop with Windows 7.

It has some very anoying quick launch keys on the left. These keys open the calculator, printing, web browsing. As they are on the left of the keyboard, I keep accidentally pressing them.

How can I disable them?

Thank you, regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to disable most of the media keys by remapping them using Randy Rants' SharpKeys (freeware, Windows):
http://www.randyrants.com/2006/07/sharpkeys_211.html

I have mapped each media key to the key at it's right:

- calculator is now left ctrl
- internet is caps lock
- mediasmart is tab

The print button is a problem, as it actually sends the CTRL + P combination. You can't disable it without also turning off the P key.

Comment: Here is a similar solution using AutoHotKey it manages to disable the left ctrl + P combo (and thus the print key) while leaving the right ctrl + P combo working 
http://dizyart.com/disabling-action-keys-on-hp-g62.html

Comment: Long time ago I used the solution you comented nad It works like a charm. I forgot about this question, you get the accepted answer.

Comment: I finally re-enabled the print button. Ctrl+P is launches "Goto Anything" on SublimeText, it's nice to have it on a single key :)

Answer (score 0):

Most are stored in the registry

If you look in the registry for

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Appkey

you will find numbered keys under "appkey"

these are where some of your quicklaunch keys are. (Internet and calc keys should be 7 and 18 respectively.

The mediasmart key is in a different location

> HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\MobilePc\HotStartButtons\2

you can either change what program launches with those keys or delete the default program associated with each specific key to render it inoperable, the email key cannot be disabled as far as I know. I would back up those registry keys before making any changes.

[Source of Information](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/How-do-I-customize-the-Action-Keys/m-p/379207#M36213)

There is also [software to remap the HP quicklaunch keys](http://quickplay.hostzi.com/index.html), not sure how well it works on the G62

Answer (score 0):

I tried the various registry hacks and bios settings. Nothing worked except for painter's tape.

[image]